All chromium based programs are running only at 60 fps
Arch Linux
wayland/sway

nvidia proprietary driver 565.57.01

60 hz | 144 hz | 60 hz monitor setup

All is smooth except chromium (chrome, vscode). Notably, when I unplug my two lesser monitors and reboot, chromium becomes smooth, but only until I reboot next time. I read on similar refresh rate issues, but they mostly seem to be targeting xorg.
This question over manjaro forum addresses pretty much the same issue, but the thread did not lead to a solution https://forum.manjaro.org/t/all-chromium-based-programs-are-running-only-at-60-fps/68175
Arch wiki page leads to an opened issue over google bug tracker, but no luck there either, google does not seem to care that much https://issues.chromium.org/issues/40761642
Is it even possible to fix, given the current state of things? Or is there some usable workaround? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Oh, darn, I recognize my own issue. :-) At least Google has fixed it for Xorg. I'm not using Wayland, so I can't say how to fix it there. On Xorg, even when it was still an issue, running xrandr -s 1  or whatever your real resolution/refresh rate are xrandr --output DP-2 --rate 240.0 --primary --mode 2560x1440  was enough to fix Chome's behavior. Are you sure you're running Chrome in native mode? Try this: chrome --enable-features=VaapiVideoDecodeLinuxGL --use-gl=angle --use-angle=gl --ozone-platform=wayland (you need to exit it first and make sure it's not running ps ax | grep chrome)

Just like @Artem has guessed I was not running in native mode. So adding --ozone-platform=wayland flag fixed the issue.

Glad that worked. Don't forget to accept your own answer to help folks searching for accepted answers.
